# Combobox widget from ipywidget is not working

Tags: python, combobox, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I have installed the latest `ipywidgets` version 7.5.1 and I use Jupyter nb version 6.0.2. Other `ipywidgets` work well. But I do not get any output with the Combobox. No error messages.

```
widgets.Combobox(# value='John', placeholder='Choose Someone', options=['Paul', 'John', 'George', 'Ringo'], description='Combobox:', ensure_option=True, disabled=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to **remove** the `#` inside the Combobox parenthesis.

Try executing this command:

```
widgets.Combobox(value='John', placeholder='Choose Someone', options=['Paul', 'John', 'George', 'Ringo'], description='Combobox:', ensure_option=True, disabled=False)
```